# Parsing XML using ksoap2

Tags: android, xml, parsing, ksoap2

Can anyone help me to parse this xml with ksoap2??

```
<s:Envelope
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <GetTurnoverResponse
        xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <GetTurnoverResult
                xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/blablabla"
            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:Turnover>
                <a:Amount>369.2000000</a:Amount>
                <a:CurrencyID i:nil="true"/>
                <a:DateAndTime>2010-10-01T10:00:00</a:DateAndTime>
                <a:ForeignAmount>461.50</a:ForeignAmount>
                <a:ForeignCurrencyID>Euro</a:ForeignCurrencyID>
                <a:StoreNumber>101</a:StoreNumber>
            </a:Turnover>
</GetTurnoverResult>
    </GetTurnoverResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

i am not sure actually that i am getting any response or not. thus i can't parsing it.

Request XML is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProFashionAllServices">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <ns1:GetTurnover>
     <ns1:sessionID>12674579771167587539</ns1:sessionID>
  <ns1:selection>
    <ns2:EndDate>2010-10-01</ns2:EndDate>
    <ns2:StartDate>2010-10-01</ns2:StartDate>
  </ns1:selection>
   </ns1:GetTurnover>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My request is like this:

```
public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/ITurnoverService/GetTurnover";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetTurnover";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private String response;
private boolean network;

private Context mContext;

public LoadData(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    //String conString = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("url", "http://wsa.pfagroup.nl:1662/OOPServices/");
    String URL = "http://wsa.pfagroup.nl:1662/OOPServices/" +"TurnoverService.svc";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("sessionID", arg0[0]);
    request.addProperty("EndDate", arg0[1]);
    request.addProperty("StartDate", arg0[1]);

    Log.i("doINaaaaaaaaaaaa", arg0[1]);
    Log.i("doINaaaaaaaaaaaa", arg0[0]);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    httpTransport.debug = true;
    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        network = true;
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("HTTPAAAAA", e.getMessage());
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("IOAAAAA", e.getMessage());
        response = "Check Your Network Connection";
        network = false;
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("XMLAAAAA", e.getMessage());
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } //send request

    if(network){
        SoapObject result = null;
        try {
            result = (SoapObject )envelope.getResponse();
            //response = result.getProperty("GetTurnoverResult").toString();
            Log.i("responseeeeeeeeee",String.valueOf(result.getPropertyCount()));
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("SOAPAAAA", e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

error message that are showed in logcat:

```
18610-18895/com.******.*** E/SOAPAAAA﹕ De server kan de aanvraag niet verwerken als gevolg van een interne fout. Voor meer informatie over de fout kunt u IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults inschakelen (vanuit ServiceBehaviorAttribute of vanuit het configuratiegedrag <serviceDebug>) voor de server zodat de uitzonderingsgegevens naar de client worden teruggestuurd, of u kunt tracering inschakelen. Raadpleeg hiertoe de documentatie van Microsoft .NET Framework SDK en controleer de traceringslogboeken voor de server.
```

is my request wrong?? Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

your request is not set as in namespace. create PropertyInfo and set namespace, type, name and value to PropertyInfo. and, add this object to request. you have to do that for all three parameter

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
PropertyInfo p = new PropertyInfo();
p.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
p.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
p.setName("sessionID");
p.setValue(arg0[0]);
request.addProperty(p);

SoapObject selection = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"selection");
PropertyInfo EndDate = new PropertyInfo();
EndDate.setNamespace("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProFashionAllServices");
EndDate.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
EndDate.setValue("2010-10-01");
selection.addProperty(EndDate);

PropertyInfo StartDate = new PropertyInfo();
StartDate .setNamespace("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProFashionAllServices");
StartDate .setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
StartDate .setValue("2010-10-01");
selection.addProperty(StartDate );

request.addSoapObject(selection);
```

Comment: nope. SoapObject.setNamespace method not found. but i think i am adding three property serially. but those are nested . StartDate and EndDate are in sessionID property. is this a problem??

Comment: sorry , this function is in propertyinfo. I am updating my answer

Comment: this is also not working. same error. but i think i am adding three property serially. but those are nested . StartDate and EndDate are in sessionID property. is this a problem??

Comment: yes, StartDate and EndDate are nested. please check my update again

Comment: I did not try this and I am not sure it works. ns2 is ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProFashionAllServices". I think you can specify it as string

Comment: Thanks at least you are trying to help me . But it's not working.. new error: E/SOAPAAAA﹕ Er is een uitzondering opgetreden in de formatter bij de poging het bericht Er is een fout opgetreden tijdens de poging parameter http://tempuri.org/:selection te deserialiseren. Het InnerException-bericht is Fout in regel 1 positie 457. Het element http://tempuri.org/:selection bevat gegevens van een type dat wordt toegewezen aan de naam http://tempuri.org/:selection. De deserializer kent geen typen die aan deze naam zijn toegewezen. U kunt dit probleem omzeilen door DataContractResolver te .........

Comment: you can see request content and try to figure out what is wrong. HttpTransportSE ht = ..; ht.debug = true; , then you can see request as xml on ht.requestDump

Comment: Single Level Property service working fine. I am only facing problem with multi level property service.. I have debugged. requestDump is always null.. The session i am getting with another service which is working so nice as there is only single level property username and password. Can anyone help?? @Adem's  Solution's take me very closer. may be i am missing something..

Comment: you should set true to ht.debug before making request. and, you can get request after calling "call" function of ht

Comment: I have set ht.debug = true.. you can see my request. I have already posted this. I can debug. But responseDump is null :(

Comment: i have found something like this:                                             <xs:sequence><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sessionID" type="xs:unsignedLong"/><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="selection" nillable="true" type="q1:TurnoverSelection"/></xs:sequence>                       selection has a type. how to set that?? any idea?? kindly help. This link may help: [link](http://wsa.pfagroup.nl:1662/OOPServices/TurnoverService.svc?SingleWSDL)

Comment: successful requestdump:<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <v:Header />
 <v:Body>
  <StartSession xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1">
   <username i:type="d:string">a</username>
   <password i:type="d:string">b</password>
  </StartSession>
 </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>

Comment: successful responsedump:<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <s:Body>
  <StartSessionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <StartSessionResult>2150451888784248060</StartSessionResult>
  </StartSessionResponse>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

Comment: unsuccessful requestdump:<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <v:Header />
  <v:Body>
    <GetTurnover xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1">
      <n0:sessionID i:type="d:string" xmlns:n0="http://tempuri.org/">17167876979221459574</n0:sessionID>
      <n1:selection i:type="n1:selection" xmlns:n1="http://tempuri.org/">

Comment: <n2:EndDate i:type="d:string" xmlns:n2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProFashionAllServices">2010-06-20</n2:EndDate>
        <n3:StartDate i:type="d:string" xmlns:n3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProFashionAllServices">2010-06-20</n3:StartDate>
      </n1:selection>
    </GetTurnover>
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>

Comment: unsuccessful responsedump:<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <s:Body>
  <s:Fault>
   <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</faultcode>
   <faultstring xml:lang="nl-NL">Er is een uitzondering opgetreden in de formatter bij de poging het bericht Er is een fout opgetreden tijdens de poging parameter http://tempuri.org/:selection te deserialiseren. Het InnerException-bericht is Fout in regel 1 positie 457.Het element http://tempuri.org/:selection bevat gegevens

Comment: van een type dat wordt toegewezen aan de naam http://tempuri.org/:selection. De deserializer kent geen typen die aan deze naam zijn toegewezen. U kunt dit probleem omzeilen door DataContractResolver te gebruiken of door het type dat overeenkomt met selection toe te voegen aan de lijst met bekende typen, bijvoorbeeld door het kenmerk KnownTypeAttribute te gebruiken of door het toe te voegen aan de lijst met bekende typen die aan DataContractSerializer worden doorgegeven.. Zie InnerException voor meer details. te deserialiseren.
   </faultstring>
  </s:Fault>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

Comment: can you have a look on this?

Comment: Thanks a lot .. problem solved ... @Adem Without your help, it will take more time.. I will post the actual solution and reason behind the error after getting free. :)